# Navigation Component - Starting destination is incorrect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I started noticing something in my app the other day and its wildly inconsistent. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't.

I am using the Navigation Component to handle navigation in the app and I started noticing that sometimes, when popping the backstack via the action bar back button or the device back button, it returns to a fragment that is no longer the starting destination (or at least shouldn't be).

In my case the app starts in MainFragment and once authenticated moves to DashboardFragment. This is a pretty common scenario.

Navigation in the app is pretty flat. most of the time its only 1 level deep so nearly all views are accessible from the dashboard.

The app starts at a login view as many do and then to a dashboard where the session will remain as the "start destination". To accomplish this, its done in the nav_graph using popUpTo and popUpToInclusive.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.example.view.fragments.MainFragment"
    android:label="Welcome">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_dashboardFragment"
        app:destination="@id/dashboardFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
    android:name="com.example.view.fragments.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="@string/dashboard_header" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_notificationsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/notificationsFragment" />
</fragment>
```

When the user successfully authenticates and its time to go to the dashboard, I use NavController.navigate() to send them there.

```
findNavController().navigate(
    MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDashboardFragment()
)

// This should have the same result and it does appear to be affected by the same issue
// findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_dashboardFragment)
```

I have an action bar with a back arrow and a navigation drawer. In the main activity I need to define the AppBarConfiguration and override onSupportNavigateUp()

```
lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Timber.d("onCreate()")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // There is 2 different drawer menu's respectfully.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.mainFragment,
            R.id.dashboardFragment
        ), binding.drawerLayout
    )

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
...
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    Timber.d("-> onSupportNavigateUp()")
    val breadcrumb = navController
        .backStack
        .map { it.destination }
        .filterNot { it is NavGraph }
        .joinToString(" > ") { it.displayName.split('/')[1] }

    Timber.d("Backstack: $breadcrumb")
    Timber.d("Previous backstack entry: ${navController.previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.displayName}")

    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
...
```

The logs look like this when we step back and it is *working correctly*

```
D/MainActivity: -> onSupportNavigateUp()
D/MainActivity: Backstack: dashboardFragment > testingFragment
D/MainActivity: Previous backstack entry: com.example:id/dashboardFragment
D/DashboardFragment: -> onCreateView()
D/BaseFragment: -> onCreateView()
D/DashboardFragment: -> onViewCreated()
```

I also noticed when using the hamburger in the action bar that it also calls onSupportNavigateUp()

```
D/MainActivity: -> onSupportNavigateUp()
D/MainActivity: pendingAction: false
D/MainActivity: Backstack: dashboardFragment
D/MainActivity: Previous backstack entry: null
```

When I use the drawer to navigate to a destination I do see this in the logs and im not sure where/why this is returned or if it has any importance

```
I/NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination com.example:id/mainFragment as it was not found on the current back stack
```

Now, when its *NOT* working correctly, this is what the logs look like

```
D/MainActivity: -> onSupportNavigateUp()
D/MainActivity: Backstack: mainFragment > testingFragment
D/MainActivity: Previous backstack entry: com.example:id/mainFragment
D/MainFragment: -> onCreateView()
D/BaseFragment: -> onCreateView()
D/MainFragment: -> onViewCreated()
```

This really feels like the popUpTo and popUpToInclusive properties are not being applied (sometimes) when performing the navigation from main fragment to dashboard fragment. It's also suspicious that even though the dashboard fragment is not set as the new starting destination but also its missing from the backstack. Assuming the properties were NOT applied I would expected to see the breadcrumb `Backstack: mainFragment > dashboardFragment > testingFragment`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), your welcome fragment should absolutely never be the start destination of your graph. There's a guide [specifically about conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) for this exact case.

Comment: @ianhanniballake the app's welcome fragment IS the login fragment. There is no other view (like a landing/welcome view) that triages between the login and dashboard. If the user logs in correctly, it should move to the dashboard and be set as the new starting point. This is so that if the app is closed and its within an app timeout period we skip the login and jump back into the dashboard. Adding another fragment into the mix of this would not present a view and thus would just be used for logic and then stepping back from login or dashboard would need to handle exiting the app.

Comment: That's not what any of those docs say. They say your Dashboard destination should be the start destination and it should be responsible for _conditionally_ navigating the user to the login screen if they aren't logged in.

Comment: @ianhanniballake based on your statements and applying my app structure to the example of conditional navigation, you are saying the my starting destination would be the profile fragment. This app cannot be used without authentication. the login view is the only view that can be seen without being authenticated. Assuming I set the dashboard as the starting destination and conditionally redirect to the login, I then need to set that as the starting destination to isolate the user to only that view. if they navigate up/back they are returned to the dashboard which they MUST be authenticated for.

Comment: Your dashboard would be the start destination - the fixed start destination that the Principles of Navigation specifically point out.

Answer (score 0):

While there may certainly be a better procedure to follow (as outlined in the Principles of Navigation in the previous comments) the overhead of the change introduces a plethora of new errors and the scope is too large at this time.

Its still unknown why popUpTo and popUpToInclusive are not reliable via XML when navigating (even using NavDirections) however, thus far, passing the NavOptions while navigating seems to resolve the issue.

```
findNavController().navigate(
    MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDashboardFragment(),
    NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.mainFragment, true).build()
)
```

Thus far the issue has yet to arise again.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in Ian's first link:

> The back stack always has the start destination of the app at the bottom of the stack.

Your *start destination* is the "home" one in a navigation graph, the one identified with the little house icon. Set with the `startDestination` attribute in the XML. When the Navigation library creates a backstack, it always has that destination at the bottom. And it will always be there, even if you try to avoid it with the `poUpTo` attributes.

That's why if there's a fragment you consider your "home" one, like your dashboard, that needs to explicitly be your `startDestination`. It's the last thing a user will see if they back out of your app. If you have something like a login or welcome screen as the start destination, they'll back out to that.

Which is why you need to set the "home" fragment as the start destination, and then [handle any extra navigation to a login or welcome screen from there](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional). It's just how the Navigation stuff is designed to work. If you try and work around it (I did!) you'll run into other problems, and a lot of the nice features like automatic backstack recreation might not work properly